# OpenCV2: Calculate gradient for color images

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

I am using the following Python code to apply Sobel derivatives to an image:

```
image = scipy.ndimage.imread(FILE_NAME, True)
image = image.astype('float64')
gradx = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
grady = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
```

The code works when I pass `True` to `imread` to convert to grayscale. When I decide to apply Sobel to each image component, I pass `False` and the array returned in empty. Is there a way to get gradient computed for each color component?

Comment: Are you sure the array returns empty? I tried out the same code and used `cv2.imshow()` to see the result.

Comment: Did you call imread with False on an RGB jpeg?

Comment: yes I did it both on a `jpeg` and a `png` image